# Vulkan CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: android, cmake, vulkan

I'm trying to make an android application that uses the Vulkan API for rendering, but I always get the "undefined reference to 'vkCreateInstance'" message.

Here is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

add_library( vulkan_activity
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/vulkan_activity.cpp)

add_library( vulkan_stuff
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/vulkan_stuff.cpp)

add_library( vulkan_buffers
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/vulkan_buffers.cpp)

find_library( log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries( native-lib
                       vulkan_stuffx
                       vulkan_activity
                       vulkan_buffers
                       vulkan
                           ${log-lib})
```

And this is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.game.productions.phenyl.futuroland"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -v"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

[image]

I want to build my application from scartch, so I don't want get anwsers like use the samples.

Comment: **Exact** error message, please. With information which object refers to the undefined symbol.

Comment: Probably misses `target_link_libraries( vulkan_stuff vulkan )`?

Comment: The error message is related with building `vulkan_stuff` which you don't link with `vulkan`. Exactly as pointed by krOoze above.

Answer (score 3):

Android only has libvulkan.so on API 26 and higher (Nougat). Some devices supported it on Marshmallow, but you're not guaranteed that libvulkan.so will be present on API < 26, so the NDK won't let you link against it unless your NDK target platform is >= 26, since otherwise your app won't even launch on many of the devices that you say you want to be able to run on (minSdkVersion 16).

If you set minSdkVersion to 26, your native code should build against that version of the NDK headers/libraries, and libvulkan.so will be available at link time.

Or, if you're careful to only try to load your shared library that links against libvulkan.so when you're running on a Nougat device, you could leave minSdkVersion alone and add `externalNativeBuild { cmake { arguments "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-26" } }`. You'll want to carefully test on pre-Nougat devices or emulator images, since it's easy to accidentally end up with library dependencies that don't exist on earlier versions of the OS.

Or, instead of linking against libvulkan.so directly, you can use dlopen to load libvulkan.so at runtime, with a fallback or graceful exit if it fails, and then use dlsym() to get a pointer to vkGetInstanceProcAddr, and load everything else using that. This is the only way to use Vulkan on the Marshmallow devices that have it.